# Java framework for multiple scheduled jobs

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, apache-camel

I'd like to ask if anyone can suggest proper framework for backend scheduled jobs. Currently whole backend is based on multiple scheduled jobs. All the jobs are written in java and deployed on linux machine. Those jobs are controlled by cron (using crontab) and simple bash scripts as a wrappers so basically I have a couple of jars (they all are spring based uber-jars [with dependencies]) which are fired periodically. Those java modules are doing various things like processing csv/xml files, getting data from webservices, calling external APIs (HTTP) and collecting data from FTP.
Is there a framework so that I would be able to have all the modules in one place and simply manage them? I was thinking about camel (I used it before) but the must have for me is:

1. ability to deploy/undeploy single module without interrupting the rest of the modules.
2. ability to reschedule jobs (cron expression) in the runtime.

Camel is almost perfect because it has all the features for external integration (FTP, HTTP, WS) and also easy quartz integration. I don't know If it's achievable to have multiple modules and deploy/undeploy them in the runtime.

Maybe there is some other frameworks which are going to fit my needs. Please suggest.

Comment: What's wrong with cron?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Currently whole backend is working fine but...but I feel that I can save some time when for example camel have all the integration modules in place.

Comment: Concerning the module part you might want to have a look at OSGi.

Answer (score 1):

If planning to do this in Java/Scala, try using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)
It (also) offers a CRON like syntax for scheduling jobs.

We have our "modules" deployed as webapps on a simple servlet container (jetty) and trigger actions on them using a Quartz scheduler (also in a webapp to expose a simple UI)

Answer (score 0):

For managing the loading and unloading of modules, you might want to look at something based on OSGI like [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) which seems especially good with module management in the way you're describing (I admit I don't quite understand your requirement for loading and unloading modules).  Add Quartz to ServiceMix for scheduling jobs.